# WHERE IN with Doctrine 2 DBAL

Tags: mysql, doctrine, dbal

How to use a `WHERE IN` clause with Doctrine DBAL ?

The following query doesn't work, it search the name `"Bob","Elvis","Bill"` (as a string) :

```
$users = $dbc->fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN(:users_names)", array(
    'users_names' => '"Bob","Elvis","Bill"'
));
```

I tried with an array, it's the same problem.

Comment: Im looking for the same question... Can't find any solution... !!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
 $searchParameters = array("Bob","Elvis","Bill");

    $users = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN (?1)";
    $q = $em->createQuery($users)
       ->setParameter(1, $searchParameters);

    $result = $q->execute();
```

Comment: Actually you can omit the number after the question mark `?1 -> ?`

There is also a 'bug' in the API which let start the index number at 0.

See here http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-804 and there https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/523.